# Blotchy finish on stain job

Tags: wood, staining

I sanded the western pine with 80 then 160 , I admit I put too much stain on at first to make it darker , now I have I have clear blotchy spots on it , any advice is greatly aprreciated!

Thanks

Brad

Comment: Hi, welcome to SE. Could you do a search on the words *pine blotching* or *pine blotchy* please? As you'll see this has been covered here multiple times from various perspectives.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix blotchy grey stain that was not absorbed evenly into pine?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/4996/how-do-i-fix-blotchy-grey-stain-that-was-not-absorbed-evenly-into-pine)